# Method is missing in Fragment or has incorrect signature

Tags: java, android, xml

So I'm trying to make an onclick event for a button in a fragment I made:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fragment_1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/update_text"
        android:onClick="onUpdatePressed" // here is the onclick
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf    ="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the java class for this fragment:

```java
package com.hfad.projekt;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

    public void onUpdatePressed(View view) { 
             // here is the method that is supposed to be executed onclick
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        String text = pref.getString("text", "Empty");
        textView.setText("sample text");
        Log.i("Tag", "onClick: ");
    }
}
```

But android studio tells me Method 'onUpdatePressed' is missing in 'FirstFragment' or has incorrect signature and Method 'onUpdatePressed(android.view.View)' is never used.
Can you help me solve this issue?

I've tried putting the method in the activity that the fragment is put inside of:

```java
package com.hfad.projekt;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private GestureDetector detector;
    private static final int NAV_F1 = R.id.f1;
    private static final int NAV_F2 = R.id.f2;
    private static final int NAV_F3 = R.id.f3;
    private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle =
                new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                        drawer,
                        toolbar,
                        R.string.nav_open_drawer,
                        R.string.nav_close_drawer);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
        View view = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        detector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureListener());
        view.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    }

    View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };
    class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
        private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 200;
        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("TAG","onDown: ");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onSingleTapConfirmed: ");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onLongPress: ");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onDoubleTap: ");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                                float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onScroll: ");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                               float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onFling: ");
            try {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Gesture detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
                float diffAbs = Math.abs(event1.getY() - event2.getY());
                float diff = velocityX - velocityY;

                if (diffAbs > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;

                if (-diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    MainActivity.this.onLeftSwipe();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Home", "Error on gestures");
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void onLeftSwipe() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        shareActionProvider =
                (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
        setShareActionIntent("Dzień dobry");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    private void setShareActionIntent (String text){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment;
        Intent intent = null;
        if(id == NAV_F1) {
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
        }
        else if(id == NAV_F2) {
            fragment = new SecondFragment();
        }
        else if(id == NAV_F3) {
            fragment = new ThirdFragment();
        }
        else {
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        } else {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void onUpdatePressed(View view) {
        // here is the method that is supposed to be executed onclick
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String text = pref.getString("text", "Empty");
        textView.setText("sample text");
        Log.i("Tag", "onClick: ");
    }
}
```

But that yields the same problem.

Comment: Where is the code for `SecondFragment`?

Comment: I accidentally put the wrong error in the description of my issue at first, but I fixed it. SecondFragment has a similar issue. Should I put it in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution somewhere else:

```java
package com.hfad.projekt;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.updateButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        String text = pref.getString("text", "Empty");
        textView.setText("sample text");
        Log.i("Tag", "onClick: ");
    }
}
```

the fragment had to implement View.OnClickListener and set an onClick event
i also set the android:onClick attribute of the button in the xml file to `onClick`